# Can I create a custom property for the modifier stack?

Tags: modifiers, drivers, properties

I'm adding expression drivers to my modifiers structure. One of the variables I constantly use in different modifiers is the number of frames. Is there any way to attach the driver to a custom property that will be located in my modifiers stack so I see it while working with other parameters in my modifiers? The modifiers that I am using don't have a custom properties panel. But perhaps there is a trick?...

Comment: Hii, let´s see. So you want add a driver to one of your modifiers, but the modifier itself doesn,t have a custom properties panel? Which modifiers are you using? Can you also post a screenshot of what you're trying to do? :).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a custom property of an object? You can see it and modify it in Numbers Panel while working on modifiers:

[image]

(after creating the property simply right-click on the field and choose "copy as a new driver", then paste that driver in your modifiers)

Also remember you can setup a layout where you can see the contents of multiple instances of the Properties Editor:

[image]